# Connection of Google Cloud Functions in Java to Firebase Realtime Database too slow

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm starting with Cloud Functions in Java, since I have more familiarity with this language than the usual Javascript. The thing is that I implemented a test Java function, triggered by `OnCreate` on Firebase Database. The function works ok, sometimes taking around 4 seconds to finish (when passes too much time without being called). But the problem is with the read/write on the database. When I just upload the function to cloud, it cannot connect to the database (or takes at least 15 minutes!!). After that, it seams that the connection stabilizes, but still taking too much time (2 to 5 seconds) to update some values in a transaction. Above the function code:

```
package functions;


import com.google.cloud.functions.*;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.*;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.CompletionListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.Transaction.Handler;
import com.google.firebase.database.Transaction.Result;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class App implements RawBackgroundFunction {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
    
    @Override
    public void accept(String json, Context context) throws Exception {

        String[] caminhos = context.resource().split("/");
        
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
                .setProjectId("pontinho-e7dd7")
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://pontinho-e7dd7.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();


        if(FirebaseApp.getApps().size() == 0)FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        
        FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference();
        
        int i = 0;
        for(String s:caminhos) {
            i++;
            if(s.equals("messages"))break;
        }
        
        myRef.child("messages").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    data.getRef().child("c").runTransaction(new Handler() {

                        //This update is taking too much time. (it updates first the entry that cause the trigger and later update the other values;
                        @Override
                        public Result doTransaction(MutableData currentData) {
                            if(currentData.getValue() != null)currentData.setValue(currentData.getValue(Integer.class)+1);
                            else currentData.setValue(1);
                            return Transaction.success(currentData);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
                            logger.info("Updated c");
                            
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                logger.info("Canceled");
                
            }
            
        });
        
        
        if(caminhos.length >= i) {
            logger.info("pushId: "+caminhos[i]);
            myRef.child("messages").child(caminhos[i]).child("confirm").setValue(true,  new CompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference ref) {
                    if(error != null)logger.info("Erro: "+error.getMessage());
                    else logger.info("ref: "+ref.toString());
                }
                
            });
        }
        
    }
}
```

PS. Sorry for the mess code, it's just a test.

The command that I use to upload the function to cloud functions was:

```
gcloud functions deploy TesteJava --entry-point functions.App --trigger-event providers/google.firebase.database/eventTypes/ref.create --trigger-resource projects/_/instances/pontinho-e7dd7/refs/messages/{pushId}/original --runtime java11 --min-instances 1
```

Now, I don't implement any authentication keys to the function (and I don't know if I should, 'cause after all the connection is being made, but too slowly).

Another point is that my Javascript functions access and returns data from Firebase almost instantaneously.

Can someone see what can be happening here?

Comment: It seems to be a problem envolving low use of the function. I put the trigger into a rate of ~8 invokes/second and the time response dropped to 10~30ms.

Comment: Hi, could you please check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#min) and see if it helps.

Comment: Hey @MarcAnthonyB, I sow the documentation, tried to define --min-instances to 2, but when I keep a time without access the function, it still loses the connection to firebase and takes minutes to reconnect. What am I missing?

Comment: Hello? please? Still the same